# The redirect to thank you page is not working in my PHP code, using template

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to PHP. I have been using this example from a website and the redirect to thank you page is not working, can anyone solve why? Also I'm not getting the email to myself either, I have got the example code from: http://form.guide/email-form/html-email-form.html

After downloading the full code it just redirects to the PHP codes instead of going to the thank you page.

```html
if( empty($errors))
{
 $to = $myemail; 
 $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $firstname";
 $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
 " Here are the details:\n Name: $firstname \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 
 
 $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
 
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 //redirect to the 'thank you' page
 header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
 <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by" errors in PHP's error logs?

Comment: how do i check this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot:

`<?php`

in the first line of your code. Php interpreter doesn't understant where your code starts and you see php code as html.

Comment: sorry i did not add everything on this post because it said I did not have enough txt to code ratio when i tried to post... -_- anyhow it is on there

Comment: If this issue still not solved. What do you mean 'it just redirects to the PHP codes' ? Can you send a picture? And can you send screenshot of your code if it's not a full version.